# async await in mounted lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want my component to wait until the promise is resolve in the mounted lifecycle hook but it keeps showing "undefined" (because the data is not there when the component is rendered).

```
<template>
    <div class="min-w-[800px] w-full h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <TheHeader />
            <div class="flex mt-4 h-[830px] overflow-hidden">
                <section id="incoming-chats" class="min-w-[344px] px-2">
                    <BaseButton buttonType="btnPrimary" class="w-full mb-4"
                        >Serve Request</BaseButton
                    >
                    <TheChatQueue class="max-h-screen overflow-y-scroll pb-4" />
                </section>
                <section id="content" class="w-full mx-2 pr-2" v-if="dataReady">
                    <BaseTabsWrapper>
                        <BaseTab
                            v-for="chatSession in incomingChatSessions"
                            :key="chatSession.id"
                            :title="chatSession.endUser.name"
                        >
                            <p>{{ chatSession }}</p>
                        </BaseTab>
                    </BaseTabsWrapper>
                </section>
                <!-- <section id="content" class="w-full mx-2 pr-2">
                    Please take a chat
                </section> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import BaseButton from '@/components/BaseButton.vue'
import BaseClientHeader from '../components/BaseClientHeader.vue'
import BaseTabsWrapper from '@/components/BaseTabsWrapper.vue'
import BaseTab from '@/components/BaseTab.vue'
import BaseTicketEditor from '@/components/BaseTicketEditor.vue'
import BaseTicketHistorical from '@/components/BaseTicketHistorical.vue'
import TheChatQueue from '@/components/TheChatQueue.vue'
import TheHeader from '@/components/TheHeader.vue'
import TheChatArea from '@/components/TheChatArea.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        BaseButton,
        // BaseClientHeader,
        BaseTabsWrapper,
        BaseTab,
        // BaseTicketEditor,
        // BaseTicketHistorical,
        // TheChatArea,
        TheChatQueue,
        TheHeader,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            dataReady: false,
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        try {
            await this.callWebsocket()
            this.dataReady = true
        } catch {
            console.log('error')
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            incomingChatSessions: 'chatSession/getIncomingChatSessions',
        }),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            callWebsocket: 'websocket/processWebsocket',
        }),
    },
}
</script>
```

As you can see in order to create a dynamic tab menu I'm looping within a computing value coming from a vuex module that process a websocket. The main problem here is that even when I have a flag in the main component (dataReady) the component is empty when rendered.

Here's the websocket module that includes the processwebsocket action. The important part for all of this is inside the "case 'chat-updated':" part of the code:

```
export const namespaced = true
export const state = {
    connected: false,
    error: null,
    connectionId: '',
    incomingChats: [],
    socket: {},
}
export const actions = {
    async processWebsocket({ dispatch, rootState, commit }) {
        const socket = await new WebSocket('wss://xyz')
        socket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log('Websocket connected.')
            commit('SET_CONNECTION', event.type)
            dispatch(
                'sendMessage',
                JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello, server.' })
            )
        }
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            const socketData = JSON.parse(event.data)
            const socketDataType = socketData.type
            if (
                socketData.connectionId &&
                socketData.connectionId !== state.connectionId
            ) {
                commit('SET_CONNECTION_ID', socketData.connectionId)
                dispatch(
                    'shifts/updateEventsSubscription',
                    rootState.token.agentId,
                    {
                        root: true,
                    }
                )
            } else {
                switch (socketDataType) {
                    case 'incoming-chats-updated':
                        commit('SET_INCOMING_CHATS', socketData.incomingChats)
                        break
                    case 'chat-updated':
                        console.log(socketData)
                        const chatSession = socketData.chat
                        const chatEvents = chatSession.events
                        const chatState = chatEvents.length - 1
                        if (
                            chatEvents[chatState].type === 'ChatAgentAssigned'
                        ) {
                            dispatch(
                                'chatSession/fetchChatSession',
                                chatSession,
                                {
                                    root: true,
                                }
                            )
                        } else {
                            console.log(
                                `Other Event ${chatEvents[chatState].type}`
                            )
                        }
                        break
                }
            }
        }
        socket.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
        }
        socket.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
            commit('SET_CONNECTION')
            state.socket = null
            setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
        }
        commit('SET_SOCKET', socket)
    },
    async waitForOpenConnection() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const maxNumberOfAttempts = 10
            const intervalTime = 200
            let currentAttempt = 0
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (currentAttempt > maxNumberOfAttempts - 1) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    reject(new Error('Maximum number of attempts exceeded.'))
                } else if (state.socket.readyState === state.socket.OPEN) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    resolve()
                }
                currentAttempt++
            }, intervalTime)
        })
    },
    async sendMessage({ dispatch }, message) {
        if (state.socket.readyState !== state.socket.OPEN) {
            try {
                await dispatch('waitForOpenConnection', state.socket)
                state.socket.send(message)
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }
        } else {
            state.socket.send(message)
        }
    },
}
export const mutations = {
    SET_CONNECTION(state, message) {
        if (message == 'open') {
            state.connected = true
        } else state.connected = false
    },
    SET_CONNECTION_ID(state, connectionId) {
        state.connectionId = connectionId
    },
    SET_SOCKET(state, socket) {
        state.socket = socket
    },
    SET_INCOMING_CHATS(state, incomingChats) {
        state.incomingChats = incomingChats
    },
    SET_ERROR(state, error) {
        state.error = error
    },
}
export const getters = {
    getIncomingChats: (state) => {
        return state.incomingChats
    },
    getConnectionId: (state) => {
        return state.connectionId
    },
}
```

And here's the chatSession module that I use to populate the tab menu:

```
export const namespaced = true
export const state = () => ({
    chatSessions: [],
})
export const actions = {
    addChatSession({ commit }, chatSession) {
        commit('ADD_CHAT_SESSION', chatSession)
    },
    fetchChatSession({ commit }, chatSession) {
        commit('SET_CHAT_SESSION', chatSession)
    },
    clearChatSessions({ commit }) {
        commit('CLEAR_CHAT_SESSIONS')
    },
}
export const mutations = {
    ADD_CHAT_SESSION(state, chatSession) {
        state.chatSessions.push({
            ...chatSession,
        })
    },
    SET_CHAT_SESSION(state, chatSession) {
        state.chatSessions.push({
            ...chatSession,
        })
    },
    CLEAR_CHAT_SESSIONS(state) {
        state.chatSessions = []
    },
}
export const getters = {
    getIncomingChatSessions: (state) => {
        return state.chatSessions
    },
}
```

Comment: use conditional in template

Comment: the conditional is already there @kritiz

Comment: What if you change your condition to `v-if="incomingChatSessions && incomingChatSessions.length"`. If it will not work you will need to inspect your `callWebsocket` action to be sure that it's return data. Other code looks OK.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It can be done the way you did it. So the next thing to check is an action.

Comment: @Kuzzy that worked !! but to be honest I'm really intrigued why it did. I mean I have a very hard time understanding the caveats of asynchronicity within Vue and basically EVERYTHING ref. data to populate my app have to do with a websocket. The action works just fine but I guess I can't understand the difference between a flag coming from the data and evaluate the render (v-if) based on the existence or length of that computed value. Will REALLY appreciate if you develop on an answer this REALLY helped thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lowtrux it's hard to develop without seeing how your action is look like. The promise in your action may be resolved before real data come.

Comment: You are totally right @Kuzzy I have added the two vuex modules that are important to understand the data flow I guess. One that basically deals with the websocket and the other one (chatSession) that populates the getter that I used to create my dynamic tab menu. Really appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's as I said, `processWebsocket` action will resolved when connection to websocket will be established `const socket = await new WebSocket('wss://xyz')` At this moment getter `getIncomingChatSessions` will return an empty array (default value). Data in `getIncomingChatSessions` will be available only when `socket.onmessage` event will fire.

```js
async mounted() {      
 await this.callWebsocket()
 this.dataReady = true
 // this.incomingChatSessions is yet empty here but this.dataReady is true, so UI is rendering but list is empty.   
},
```

Answer (score -1):

check out [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html):
replace `this.dataReady = true` with `this.$set(this, 'dataReady', true)`

Comment: can you develop ? when I do that the promise is not resolve and it triggers the catch (and I know for sure that everything coming from the websocket is working fine).

Comment: You do not need to use`$set` for boolean values.

Comment: @Lowtrux how can we develop this? there are missing so many other files to check your code xD

Comment: As said, this doesn't need to be done, `this.dataReady = true` is perfectly ok for reactive property. @Lowtrux  You could at least log an error, so it would give an idea what's wrong. Don't catch an error if you don't have a specific goal for this, it will be handled by Vue.

Comment: Wendt88 I know you are totally right. What I meant is that I have never used $set for a boolean tho (as @Kuzzy mentioned previously) so I was just wondering why did you used it.